# Employer ran credit check without my consent

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-report, employment, employer

I’ve just started a new job as a cleaner and recieved an email from them regarding the credit check they carried out. I was never told this was going to happen or why they would need to. Does anyone know if this is allowed? I am in the U.K.

Comment: Are you sure it was a (financial) credit check and not a background check to verify criminal charges/convictions?

Comment: How did you apply for the position? Do you have copy of the application you filled out? Did you apply through a web portal? Did you read all the fine print?

Answer (score 1):

An employer should notify you if carrying out a credit check on yourself.

That said, if you were joining a finance firm or a bank etc - a credit check should be *expected* due to the nature of the environment, however they should have at least told you this would be carried out.

It could be down to human error - perhaps they forgot to ask.

That said, had you of declined the credit check, they might have asked why you don't want them looking and as such could potentially reject you from the job.

Comment: For many jobs in the US, not just in a financial environment,   a credit check is mandatory. If you decline to permit one, they don't ask why, they just drop your application from further consideration. I am not sure if this is also true in the UK, but I suspect that it is.